# resource.h is missing

Tags: winapi, resources

is it possible to generate resource header file if i got the resource.rc file?

Answer (score 0):

You mean, in an automatically manner? If so, check this: [Makeheaders](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/).

Otherwise, copy all the function and variable declarations, macros etc. from the resource.c, create a resource.h file and paste them into.